# Notepad++: Highlight Regex with different colours

Tags: notepad++

In Notepad++, you can highlight selected strings by going to **Search > Mark All > Using X style** where X is 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.

If you use **Search > Find...** (or **Ctrl+F**) you can search for terms by regular expression, and under the Mark tab, you can mark all strings that match the expression.

It would seem you cannot choose which style you mark with and it is always highlighted in red. Is there a way to mark all matching strings of a regular expression with a specific style, such as 1st, 2nd or 3rd style?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you cannot do it directly. But there are some workarounds. Try this procedure:

- Record Macro
- Find Regex 1
- TitleMenú -> Search -> Highlight All -> Apply style 1
- Stop Macro
- Play Macro 999 times

Repeat the procedure for Regex2/Style2, Regex3/Style3,...

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do what I'm looking for. When you use a "Mark All" button in the Search menu, it marks all of whatever is currently selected. For example, if you use a regex to match IP addresses and have 1.1.1.1 selected as the first match, a "Mark All" will highlight all "1.1.1.1" strings because that is what is selected. I want to mark all matches of the regex (ie. 2.2.2.2, 1.2.3.4, etc.)

Comment: That's why you record a macro. You repeat the (find next + mark all) 999 times, so all possible regexp values are marked for that color. Then, next macro for next color